# Loop through a gridview to replace the cell value

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I want to loop through a gridview  cell values and replace any value which has an asterisk like 3*,4*, ** etc to change like 3(underline), 4 underline and 8 (underline)..so basically i want to remove the asterisk and underline the inetger..Please guide me on this...thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop trough every row and cell trough this:

```
foreach(DataGridViewRow gridRow in myGridview.Rows)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < myGridview.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        if(gridRow.Cells[i].Text.Contains('*'))
        {
           //Do your thing 
           gridRow.Cells[i].Text=gridRow.Cells[i].Text.Replace(@"*", "");
           gridRow.Cells[i].Style.Font = new Font("Ariel", 8, FontStyle.Underline);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieved this by using RowDataBound Event.. No need to loop

[GridView.RowDataBound Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound(v=vs.110).aspx)

The following example demonstrates how to use the RowDataBound event to modify the value of a field in the data source before it is displayed in a GridView control.

```
void CustomersGridView_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{

  if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
  {
    // Display the company name in italics.
    e.Row.Cells[1].Text = "<i>" + e.Row.Cells[1].Text + "</i>";

  }

}
```

Comment: +1 Ah forgot that there was a databound event. this is more efficient since looping is already done on creation. Should have been the accepted answer. :)